# Missing creation time for LVM volume

Tags: lvm, proxmox

One of our storage has an lvm volume group on which multiple logical volumes are not set the creating host name and time (LV Creation host, time attribute).

These were created quite a long time ago, but unfortunately (since the date is missing) I can’t say exactly. It can be many, many years, even 8-10.

Currently, we want to pull it under a Proxmox 6 (shared lvm via fiber, currently used by Proxmox 3), which we can’t do because Proxmox 6 needs creation time.

I couldn't find a command to set an exact time for this.

Can anyone help me how to set the hostname and creation time on an lvm logical volume?

Regards,
Laszlo

Comment: Could someone help me? Specifically, this error message is given by proxmox.  

`Result verification failed (400)  
[9].ctime: type check ('integer') failed - got ''  
[8].ctime: type check ('integer') failed - got ''  
[4].ctime: type check ('integer') failed - got ''  
[7].ctime: type check ('integer') failed - got ''  
[10].ctime: type check ('integer') failed - got ''`

Answer (score 0):

sorry, I can't format in a comment.

So, lvdisplay output example ( 1 volume, but there are 32 in total, 5 of which have no creation time):

**LV Creation host, time** attribute is empty.
Probably, created under proxmox 3 - is it possible that this attribute did not exist then?

```
--- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/stvg1/vm-103-disk-1
  LV Name                vm-103-disk-1
  VG Name                stvg1
  LV UUID                sbSgG8-4nuw-RwG5-skxe-J9e1-OkGo-ImEMfO
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time , 
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                1.50 TiB
  Current LE             393216
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:20
```

and proxmox error message when trying to read lvm volumes

```
Result verification failed (400)
[9].ctime: type check ('integer') failed - got ''
[8].ctime: type check ('integer') failed - got ''
[4].ctime: type check ('integer') failed - got ''
[7].ctime: type check ('integer') failed - got ''
[10].ctime: type check ('integer') failed - got ''
```